# XGBoost decision tree machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

I got this fig when I used the XGBoost regressor (the decision tree has too many details & not clear)for a large dataset (3 MB)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ6M3.png)

Please what is the solution?

Comment: Please share the code you generated this with so others can help you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.